# Blazor Server Get User from Controller (Auth0)

Tags: server, blazor, auth0

I have based the issue from this Template from here: https://github.com/auth0-blog/blazor-quiz-manager

Which simply connects to Auth0 to authenticate users, which works perfectly fine. I can get the User info fine from the Blazor page itself perfectly fine.

However i need to get the User info from the Controller (without having to post userinfo), so i can use the logged in user info to update a db record (getting userID etc)

There are a number of people having this same issue, but never seems to be a resolution (here for example is one  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17442 )

If i add to my startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider, ServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

I can access the user from my controller :

```
   private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider auth;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _currentContext;

    public UserController(IHttpContextAccessor currentContext, AuthenticationStateProvider auth)
    {
        _currentContext = currentContext;
        this.auth = auth;
    }
var authState = await auth.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var user = authState.User;
```

Of course the issue is as it is a Singleton, i am having issues with users sharing the browser refresh. and it should be :

```
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ServerAuthenticationStateProvider>()
```

However if i use AddScoped, i get the error:

'GetAuthenticationStateAsync was called before SetAuthenticationState.'

and all hope is lost :(

Any pointers ???

Comment: Don't use `IHttpContextAccessor `, for security reason, even if it works now, after deploying you will get an error!.

Comment: THat was another option (which also doesnt work), but would rather use this "GetAuthenticationStateAsync as it seemed to work fine " what are my other options here to get it to work as Scoped ??